# How can i make custom position of inputs dropdown in angular-material?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, frontend, angular-material

I found 'md-position-mode' directive, but it works only with menu('md-menu'), help me please to find something similar for inputs dropdown

Comment: are you using angular-material? Please add tag for it and also mention it in your question!

Comment: yes, sorry i did not said

Comment: i did it, so can you be so kind to help?))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "inputs dropdown" you mean `md-select` you can use the `md-container-class` attribute with some CSS - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/VjbjBj)

Markup

```
<md-input-container>
    <label>State</label>
    <md-select id="mySelect" ng-model="ctrl.userState" md-container-class="selectList">
      <md-option ng-repeat="state in ctrl.states" value="{{state.abbrev}}" ng-disabled="$index === 1">
        {{state.abbrev}}
      </md-option>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

CSS

```
.selectList {
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

[md-select documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect)